# need a search for specific values from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, search, conditional-statements

I'm using Excel 2010. and I need a suggestion or tip for the following:

I have 2 spreadsheets. SheetA is replaced on a daily basis with changing data about disk usage.
SheetB is a report that I need to send out daily with disk usage among others.

I need disk usage nummbers from specific servers and their disks from SheetA presented in SheetB.

There are numerous ways of doing this, which all work very nice. But! they all work with formulas based on line- and column numbers. There's the catch! The linenumbers in SheetA aren't fixed. Disks are added and deleted on a regular basis, making my report difficult.
So defining a range is no option.

The format in Sheet A looks like this:

```
  A        B    C      D
1 Server1  C:   5000   1250  
2 Server1  D:   10000  500
3 Server2  C:   1000   900
4 Server2  E:   2000   1900
```

The values C and D represent Capacity and Used space
In my SheetB it should look the same.

I would like a search for in SheetA for "Server1" and "C:" and display the values found in A, B, C and D in SheetB.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to enter "Server1" and "C:" in column A&B in sheet2 anyway, so no need for a formula here. To get the value for C, use this formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!C:C,MATCH(A1&B1,Sheet1!$A:$A&Sheet1!$B:$B,0))
```

You need to enter the formula as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Adjust to column D accordingly.